# Filtering List item based on created by column using rest api

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

I have a list and I need to filter all the items based on created by column.
What to add to url to get it. I am using following end-point

```
_api/Lists/getbytitle('EmployeeInfo')/items?$filter=(Author eq  'vikash')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
_api/Lists/getbytitle('EmployeeInfo')/items?$filter=(Author eq 'vikash')
```

Your end-point should look like following instead of above

```
_api/Lists/getbytitle('EmployeeInfo')/items?$filter=AuthorId eq 'someId'
```

In REST API `Created By` column maps to the `AuthorId`. `someId` will be a number like 1, 11 or something else.

If you need to filter by `Create By` column's Name/Title, then end-point should look like following

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('EmployeeInfo')/Items?$select=Author/Title&$expand=Author&$filter=Author/Title eq 'vikash'
```

`$select` specifies which fields to return in JSON results. Put your required column separated by coma(,). For lookup

```
Your Column Name/Property Name
```

`$expand` helps to retrieve information from Lookup columns.

`$filter` specifies which items to return.

If you have time, please have a look on [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API) article.

Comment: I need it based on created by person

Comment: AuthorId and Create By are same